# iphone goes in to infinity respring loop after uninstalling tweak

Tags: ios, cydia, tweak

I wrote a tweak called Dual Time, it displays second clock on the lock screen.
Everything works fine, but on one phone (iPhone 4) after uninstalling tweak something goes wrong and the phone goes into infinity respring loop. After hard reset, phone booted, but the Cydia icon disappeared and some applications could not be open. The owner of the phone had to burn the battery down to zero, and after that he was able to put his phone in DFU and restore firmware. On my 3GS I were unable to reproduce the bug, after re-installation and uninstallation tweak on the same iPhone 4 bug also wasn't appeared. Is anybody know why is that happened? Is something wrong with my tweak?
Tweek is located at http://appstudio.org/apt

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem and i have solved it using these steps:

1. put your device in recovery (not dfu) and wait for a while. After that press both the power and home button until the phone is turned off then release the power button and wait for a few seconds.
2. you must make build custom ipsw signed with your saved shsh (you can search for that on google) then the program will ask you to put your device into the pwned dfu.
3. run tiny umbrella  and start server to avoid the problem (3194 ..etc
4. now run itunes and recover your iphone with the signed ipsw (not the original ipsw )